# How to set all values of a complex dict to the same one?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Give a very complex dict *dict_a*, i.e., some key corresponses to simple value (level-*1*), but others many corresponse to another dict (level-*n*).

My question is how to set all its values, whether level-*1* or level-*n*, to one single value, say 100.

For example:

```
a = 10
b = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3{1: 13, 2: {4: 33}}}
c = {1: a, 2: b}
```

how to set values of dict c to 0?

Comment: What is this `3{1: 13, 2: {4: 33}}`?

Comment: So the result should be `{1: 0, 2: {1: 0, 2: 0, ...}}` and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple recursive function should work:

```
def setdictvalto(d, value):
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            setdictvalto(d[k], value)
        else:
            d[k] = value
```

Demo:

```
>>> setdictvalto(c, 100)
>>> c
{1: 100, 2: {1: 100, 2: 100, 3: {1: 100, 2: {4: 100}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def setZeroes(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            setZeroes(value)
        else:
            d[key] = 0

>>> c
{1: 10, 2: {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: {1: 13, 2: {4: 33}}}}

>>> setZeroes(c)

>>> c
{1: 0, 2: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: {1: 0, 2: {4: 0}}}}
```